# Unable to check if a string contains a specific string in a for loop of a text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that reads line by line a text file (ProcessedFiles.txt). The text has many lines that represent filenames of a directory. They can be either JSON or HTML files. I would like to check if the string "json" exists in that line. I have already searched and tried a few answers like

```
if not x%%a:json=%==x%%a% echo It contains JSON
```

or even extracting the last 4 characters from the %%a

```
SET var=%%a:~-4%
```

but I must be doing something really wrong here because I cannot get it to work.
I apologize for my very limited knowledge on batch script.
Basically I want to know if each line of the text file I am reading contains the string "json". This is my for loop code i am trying to correct

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%jsonDir%ProcessedFiles.txt) do (
    echo Processing file: %%a
    SET var=%%a:~-4%
)
```

The `echo Processing file: %%a` displays the line correctly and this is what I am aiming to search if it contains the string "json".
For example, if text file ProcessedFiles.txt contains the lines
ABCD.json

BCDF.json

ABDR.html

CVBF.json etc.

when the loop reads the line ABCD.json or BCDF.json or CVBF.json then I need to know that it has encountered a JSON file, but for line ABDR.html it is not a JSON file.

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you looking to see whether the file **name** contains `json` or whether the file itself contains `json`? What do you want to display? Examples are good...use the `edit` button.

Comment: Does utility fit your task? **findstr /F:ProcessedFiles.txt /C:"JSON" /M**

Comment: @Magoo: Hi, I just edited my question with an example as you suggested. I hope it is clearer now. Thank you

Comment: The variable modifier syntax works for variables, but not for FOR-parameters. You need to copy the `%%a` value into a variable and use then delayed expansion

Comment: Unfortunately, still not so clear. If you are looking for the filenames that end `.json` within the file `...processedfiles.txt` then `findstr /i /e ".json" filename` should list those. `findstr /?` from the prompt for documentation - or many examples on SO.

Comment: Is this more like what you need? ```@For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("%jsonDir%\ProcessedFiles.txt") Do @If /I "%%~xG" == ".JSON" (Echo %%~nG is a JSON file.) Else If /I "%%~xG" == ".HTML" (Echo %%~nG is a HTML file.) Else Echo %%~nxG is neither a JSON or a HTML file.``` Please note, I've added the directory separator after `%jsonDir%`. If you have defined the variable with a trailing backward slash, remove it; it is a separator, not a terminator.

Comment: @Magoo: I used your suggestion with findstr /i /e ".json" filename and save that to a text file to loop through its contents. Did the same for ".html". A workable solution does the trick. Thank you again :)